# Save OTP for verification

Tags: authentication, caching, redis, one-time-password

I am developing a OTP service to verify users via SMS. To verify the opt message what is the best way to save the OTP? I am thinking of using a caching option like Redis.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I implemented this using redis, basically what i did was I took the mobile number/email as the key and the value as the OTP. It's working fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track. A key-value store like Redis would be the best option for this purpose. You could have simple logic like this in your preferred language:

Create an OTP -> Save it in Redis using `SET` with an expiry of whatever time you want -> On getting a request check if the key exists, if the value is right, they are verified.

It's better to use Redis for short-lived purposes like verifying user token by email, OTP, etc

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your comment, I used redis for this, basically what i did was I took the mobile number/email as the key and the value as the OTP, and set an expiration time for each key, If the OTP verification success, then  the key will be removed from the cache.